Does a spell with a casting time still require that time if cast from a scroll?
So I have a cleric wanting to use "Prayer of Healing" which takes 10 minutes to cast. The area they are in doesn't allow time passage, and so they can't use spells with casting times longer than instant.
If they cast this spell from a scroll, does the time become zero? or is it still 10 minutes?

What is 'time passage'?

I'm voting to re-open this question because it doesn't appear to be a duplicate of the other. The other question's answer does include an answer to this question, but the questions are dissimilar enough that someone searching for an answer wouldn't necessarily assume that that's the case.

@GMJoe This is a very straightforward duplicate. The fact that someone may not find one of these while searching for the other is exactly why we close questions as duplicates. The name of the spell is immaterial to the question and answer.

@ThomasMarkov Good point. I wish I'd thought of that. I'd retract my reopen vote if I could.

@GMJoe You can retract reopen votes.

@ThomasMarkov Oho! That's useful. Thanks for the info.

Yes, it takes the same time as normal.
From the Spell Scroll's description:

Casting the spell by reading the scroll requires the spell’s normal casting time.

